# Why can I cross join XMLTABLE? Why don't I have to cross apply?

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltable

I saw examples using XMLTABLE to sort comma-separated strings in Oracle. While we should never have to do this with a proper database design, it made me curious and there is one thing I don't understand at all:

Why am I allowed to cross join XMLTABLE referencing columns from the other table? I would expect to have to apply a lateral join (`CROSS APPLY`), but this doesn't seem needed. This query works:

```
select *
from 
(
  select 'b,a,d' as csv from dual
  union all
  select 'w,o,r,s,e' as csv from dual
) t
cross join xmltable
(
  'if (contains($csv, ",")) then string-join(for $str in ora:tokenize($csv, ",") order by $str return $str, ",") else $csv'
   passing t.csv as "csv"
   columns sorted varchar2(4000) path '.'
) x
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    CSV    |  SORTED   |
+-----------+-----------+
| b,a,d     | a,b,d     |
| w,o,r,s,e | e,o,r,s,w |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I am passing `t.csv` which should not be accessible on the right side of the cross join in my opinion.

Can anybody explain what is happening here? I have come to think that Oracle muddles its way through here for some reason, thus violating the SQL standard. Am I right?

If you can explain what Oracle does here, this will certainly also explain why adding this

```
where sorted <> 'x'
```

leads to unexpected results. Unexpected to me that is :-)

Result with `WHERE` clause:

```
+-----------+--------+
|    CSV    | SORTED |
+-----------+--------+
| b,a,d     | a,b,d  |
| w,o,r,s,e | a,b,d  |
+-----------+--------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9497bec423a3facbd29b49b3a40a350

Comment: This functionality was there before `cross apply` was added to Oracle, wasn't it? Not sure if that's why it's retained - it may be a kind of synonym (you [still get](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3fbb63694d9ed59d53700f38bf9a5884) your unexpected result with `cross apply`, BTW). But why should `t.csv` not be accessible?

Comment: @Alex Poole: With "should not be accessible" I mean that with `from t cross join something` t is not known on the right side of the join, so no matter if `something` is some subquery or function, I cannot use t.csv there. (This is why lateral joins had to be invented after all. :-)

Comment: Well, I know that explanation sucks somehow. I cannot use t.csv inside (i.e. within the subquery or in the parameter list of the function). This is what I am trying to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "why" question might be difficult to answer; it is likely because that is how Oracle performed correlated queries using its legacy comma-join syntax and then adding ANSI syntax later and then in Oracle 12c added `CROSS APPLY` but finding documentation to back this up will be challenging.

However, if you can force the evaluation of the correlated `CROSS JOIN` (by performing a useless row specific operation, like generating the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column) before applying the `WHERE` filter clause then you can get the query to work:

```sql
WITH t ( csv ) AS (
  select 'b,a,d'       from dual union all
  select 'w,o,r,s,e'   from dual union all
  select 'w,o,r,s,e,r' from dual
)
SELECT csv,
       sorted
FROM   (
  select ROWNUM as id,
         t.csv,
         s.sorted
  from   t
         CROSS JOIN xmltable (
           'if (contains($csv, ",")) then string-join(for $str in ora:tokenize($csv, ",") order by $str return $str, ",") else $csv'
           passing t.csv as "csv"
           columns sorted varchar2(4000) path '.'
         ) s
)
WHERE  sorted <> 'x';
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CSV         | SORTED     
> :---------- | :----------
> b,a,d       | a,b,d      
> w,o,r,s,e   | e,o,r,s,w  
> w,o,r,s,e,r | e,o,r,r,s,w
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e06f3e9b900850cb5020ed38a388ce6e)*

Comment: Thank you. I think that Alex Poole's explantion might be closer to what's really happening. Oracle introduced XMLTABLE in version 10.2g, before lateral joins were available, and had to get this working somehow. (Lateral joins only got introduced in version 12c). So, they applied some magic to get this working at that time, and as it is with magic - it can have side effects :-) It's amazing you found a workaround. This makes your answer very valueable. (I tried with /*+materialize*/ which failed utterly.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'd start looking for where Table Collection Expressions were introduced, as I am guessing that this pre-dates XMLTABLE's introduction in 10R2, and also required correlated cross joins.

Comment: Ah, you are right. We can use columns of the left-hand table in any cross-joined table function parameter list. I didn't know that. Yes, table functions got introduced before XMLTABLE, so the magic happening here stems probably from these even older days. Thank you for pointing this out.